# OData URI filter expression for NOT IN

Tags: odata, uri

I have a PowerShell script that has the following ODATA URI $filter expression.

```
...?$filter=(Web eq ''N'' or Web eq ''W'') and Item_Type ne ''I'''
```

How can I add a "NOT IN" statement similar to SQL which would be something like

```
Brand NOT IN {'A' 'B' 'C' 'D'}
```

EDIT: This is for Microsoft Business Central FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
not(property in ('v1', 'v2'))
```

For your property `Web`

```
...?$filter=not(Web in (''N'',''W'')) and Item_Type ne ''I'''
```

If `not` filter option is not supported you can use `ne` and `and` operators

```
property ne 'V1' and property ne 'V2'
```

Query:

```
...?$filter=Web ne ''N'' and Web ne ''W'' and Item_Type ne ''I'''
```

Comment: I should've mentioned it's Microsoft Business Central which gives me 
**Client requests that contain \"Not\" filter options are not supported by Dynamics 365 Business Central OData web services** 
:(

Comment: @johnrpg What about using not equal? Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the NOT filter has fixed values, so  I went with own API object definition, where I include the NOT filter either in columnDataFilter:

`DataItemTableFilter = "Interaction Template Code" = filter('<>THIS_NOT_INCLUDED*');`

Or in `onBeforeOpen` trigger

```
trigger OnBeforeOpen()
    begin
        currQuery.SETFILTER(interactionTemplateCode, <>THIS_NOT_INCLUDED*');
    end;
```